# css - How to show webpage correctly on phone's browser

Tags: html, css

I've a website .I haven't used responsive .

I used fixed sizes , the container div is 1200px and it has 3 columns. 2 menus and one content . all of them has fixed widthes and they're showing correctly in windows.

The problem is on phone's browsers . on phone's browser, it showing very bad , it doesn't show the whole website and each columns is below the next columns .

what can be the problem ?

Comment: please share your some code of html css

Answer (score 0):

you will need to add media query and given container div width to 100% in case of mobile and tablet